How to Locate and Edit Sidebar Code in JobCareer Theme to Rename Fields?
I'm using the JobCareer theme in WordPress, and I'm trying to customize the sidebar by renaming certain fields. However, I'm having trouble finding the specific file that controls the sidebar's content.
I've looked through the theme files but haven't been able to identify where the sidebar code is located. Specifically, I want to change the names of several fields in the sidebar.
Could anyone guide me on how to find the correct file responsible for the sidebar in the JobCareer theme? Any tips on how to effectively search through theme files for such customizations would also be appreciated.
I searched through all the theme files using keywords like sidebar, widget, and specific field names I want to change.

Welcome! This theme is a purchased theme - this question is better suited for the developer of the theme, since we don't have access to the files at all.

You are trying to edit sidebar template or the widgets used in the sidebar ? And by changing field name you mean translating it ?

I want to change the name of a specific field in the sidebar to something else while maintaining the same functionality. I'm not interested in altering the design—just the field name within the sidebar.
